# Loading only visible image thumbnails in scrollviewer in WPF listbox using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf

I created the following xaml

```
<Window x:Class="SampleApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MainViewModel}">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image x:Name="Thumbnail" Stretch="Fill" Width="100" Height="100" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(local:CustomScrollViewer.IsInViewport), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="Thumbnail" Property="Source" Value="{Binding Thumbnail}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Text="{Binding Path=ImageFolderpath}"></TextBlock>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Width="50" Click="Button_Click">Browse</Button>
        </StackPanel>

        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Images, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="1">
            <ListBox.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <local:CustomScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                    </local:CustomScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ListBox.Template>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

with listbox and control template using a custom scroll viewer so that only visible items can be loaded for efficiency.

Xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
            System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();

            if(result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                var vm = (this.DataContext as MainViewModel);
                vm.ImageFolderpath = dialog.SelectedPath;
                vm.LoadDirectory();
            }
        }
    }
```

MainViewmodel.cs which is binded to the xaml as its datacontext. this handles loading of bitmaps when ever required by maintaining a cache.

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    readonly Dictionary<string, BitmapSource> _cache = new Dictionary<string, BitmapSource>();

    public ObservableCollection<ImageViewModel> Images = new ObservableCollection<ImageViewModel>();

    public string ImageFolderpath = string.Empty;
    public BitmapSource GetBitmap(string name)
    {
        BitmapSource bitMap = null;

        if (!_cache.TryGetValue(name, out bitMap))
        {
            string imagePath = Path.Combine(ImageFolderpath, name);

            if (File.Exists(imagePath))
            {
                BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage();
                bmpImage.BeginInit();
                bmpImage.UriSource = new Uri(imagePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                bmpImage.DecodePixelWidth = 120;
                bmpImage.DecodePixelHeight = 120;
                bmpImage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
                bmpImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bmpImage.EndInit();

                bitMap = bmpImage;

                _cache.Add(name, bitMap);
            }
            else
            {
                Images.Remove(Images.Where((ImageViewModel vm) =>
                {
                    return vm.Name == name;
                }).FirstOrDefault());
            }
        }
        return bitMap;
    }

    void WalkDirectoryTree(System.IO.DirectoryInfo root)
    {
        System.IO.FileInfo[] files = null;
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = null;

        // First, process all the files directly under this folder
        try
        {
            files = root.GetFiles("*.*");
        }
        // This is thrown if even one of the files requires permissions greater
        // than the application provides.
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
        {

        }

        catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        if (files != null)
        {
            foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in files)
            {
                // In this example, we only access the existing FileInfo object. If we
                // want to open, delete or modify the file, then
                // a try-catch block is required here to handle the case
                // where the file has been deleted since the call to TraverseTree().
                Console.WriteLine(fi.FullName);

                Images.Add(new ImageViewModel(fi.Name, this));
            }

            // Now find all the subdirectories under this directory.
            subDirs = root.GetDirectories();

            foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirs)
            {
                // Resursive call for each subdirectory.
                WalkDirectoryTree(dirInfo);
            }
        }
    }


    public void LoadDirectory()
    {
        DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(ImageFolderpath);

        WalkDirectoryTree(dInfo);
    }
}
```

ImageViewmodel.cs holds each image information and it retrieves the bitmap from the main viewmodel.

```
class ImageViewModel
    {
        MainViewModel mMainVm;
        string mName;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return mName; }
        }

        public ImageViewModel(string name, MainViewModel vm)
        {
            mMainVm = vm;
            mName = name;
        }
        public BitmapSource Thumbnail
        {
            get { return mMainVm.GetBitmap(mName); }
        }
    }
```

customScrollViewer.cs that handles the loading of images when ever user scrolls the listbox

```
public sealed class CustomScrollViewer : ScrollViewer
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsInViewportProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsInViewport", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomScrollViewer));

    public static bool GetIsInViewport(UIElement element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(IsInViewportProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsInViewport(UIElement element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(IsInViewportProperty, value);
    }

    protected override void OnScrollChanged(ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnScrollChanged(e);

        var panel = Content as Panel;
        if (panel == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Rect viewport = new Rect(new Point(0, 0), RenderSize);

        foreach (UIElement child in panel.Children)
        {
            if (!child.IsVisible)
            {
                SetIsInViewport(child, false);
                continue;
            }

            GeneralTransform transform = child.TransformToAncestor(this);
            Rect childBounds = transform.TransformBounds(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), child.RenderSize));
            SetIsInViewport(child, viewport.IntersectsWith(childBounds));
        }
    }
}
```

After all these, when i select a folder to load images, it is traversing the folder and making the image viewmodels but in the UI, images were not displayed. Am i missing something?

Comment: You know that ListBox uses a VirtualizingStackPanel as default ItemsPanel, which loads items only when they become visible? Why is there a WrapPanel in your ScrollViewer? Is it supposed to wrap anything at all?

Comment: I'd suggest to use a standard ListBox with only image file paths in the the items class, an Image element in the ItemTemplate, and create thumbnail images by a Binding Converter in the Image.Source Binding.

Comment: @Clemens that will load the images multiple times right? so that it cause performance issues when loaded lots of images i assume

Comment: No, BitmapImages are cached by default.

Comment: @Clemens oh. thanks, in that case, if i need a wrap panel to display them like tiles as like windows explorer displays icons, i need to use a custom template right? if i do so, VirtualizingStackPanel will have no use then. right?

Comment: There is no built-in VirtualizingWrapPanel, but if you search the web you may find one.

Comment: How many images are you intending to show in the ListBox? I just tried around 500 in a standard ListBox with a WrapPanel and DecodePixelHeight = 120. Loading takes some time, but then everything runs smoothly. And loading could be done asynchronously.

Comment: all the images in the PC. more than 1000 probably